# Chrome replaces '30' with '3%' in date input when using specific font (Aspergit)

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome, fonts, webfonts

Has anyone seen this before, or has any ideas why this is happening?

The font is called 'Aspergit'.

This is a React frontend, but not sure that matters. This bug does not occur with Firefox (using the same font). It only occurs in Chrome, using this specific font, no other fonts. Also, typing, or displaying '30' anywhere else displays correctly. This is using the native input type='date'. Video of the bug: https://streamable.com/4v6u2y This has been confirmed on Linux (Manjaro) and Windows 10, using Chrome 98.0.4758.102

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out that adding "font-variant-ligatures: none;" to the inputs fixed it. Leaving this here, in case anyone else encounters this.